# CdiRunner returns error NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: junit, cdi

Added @RunWith(CdiRunner.class) to a Junit test and try to run as a Junit test and get the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanAttributes

Answer (score 0):

How do you manage your dependencies in your proeject? Are you using maven or gradle? It seems like you are missing some libraries those are supposed to be included in your project.